# Как правильно склонять прозвища женских персонажей?

Tags: склонение, ономастика, переводы, склоняемость

Возникли споры при переводе [книги](http://fanfics.me/read.php?id=68682). Там есть героини с прозвищами Дракон, Мясник и Рой.

Как правильно склонять такие "имена"? В текущем переводе *Дракон* и *Мясник* склоняются по правилам склонения слов мужского рода ("передали информацию Дракону"), а *Рой* не склоняется ("территория Рой", а не "территория Роя").

Насколько это правильно? Ваше мнение?

Comment: Драконица, Мясничиха?

Comment: Нет, прозвища именно мужские слова (Дракон, а не Драконица), вопрос грамматический, какие правила в русском языке в таком случае.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, верно в текущем переводе. Представьте себе, что девочку  называете ласково зайчонок, котёнок. Вы же скажете:"Мы с котёнком пойдём спать",моему зайчонку холодно, ведь так? А Рой - не явно мужское прозвище, чисто внешне возможно и женское, поэтому по аналогии с фамилиями на согласный  - мужская склоняется, женская нет.

Answer (score 2):

**Дракон, Мясник**  – русские слова, они склоняются даже в том случае, если являются женскими прозвищами.

**Рой** – в русском языке это неодушевленное существительное м.р., но также **это может быть иностранным именем или фамилией (мужской или женской)**, например Роб Рой. И тогда по правилам мужсое имя склоняется, а женское не склоняется.